"Embedded authoring" experience in superset
I embed Apache Superset dashboards in my application and looking to embed a sort of dashboard authoring capability like self-service data exploration, and dashboard authoring into my application.
Does superset has this options via superset embedding SDK ?
So far have't been able to find it ...
Thanks in advance !
So far have't been able to find it ...
Thanks in advance !

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
